# Aura Component not always firing on button click?

Tags: aura, screen-flow

I have created a custom List View Button that calls an Aura component that opens a modal window from which a screen flow is run.

This seems to work but I noticed that if I click on close, I go back to the previous page (as expected) but when clicking on the button again, nothing happens **unless I refresh** the screen.

Once I click on refresh, the modal window pops up again.

To add to the confusion, another object uses the same controller and this issue does not happen.

I am not sure whether I should change the controller or something else may be explaining why, but if somebody had any idea I would be grateful! (I'm pretty new to UI stuff).

Many thanks in advance!!!

Controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    
    component.set('v.isOpen', true);
    let flow = component.find('flow');
    let objectName = component.get("v.sObjectName");
    let flowApiName = "createRequest";
    
    flow.startFlow(flowApiName);
    
     
},

closeFlowModal : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isOpen", false);
    history.back();
    
},

closeModalOnFinish : function(component, event, helper) {
    if(event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED") {
        component.set("v.isOpen", false);
    }
    
},

})
```

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,lightning:availableForFlowActions,force:hasSObjectName,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
 <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="Boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>


  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
        <div style="height: 640px;">
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header slds-modal__header_empty">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" class="slds-modal__close" onclick="{!c.closeFlowModal}"/>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                        <lightning:flow aura:id="flow" onstatuschange="{!c.closeModalOnFinish}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div> 
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have fixed it by adding  `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` to the closeFlowModal method.

Answer (score 0):

```
closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId"); 
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": recId,
        "slideDevName": "Detail"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
    
},

===>   $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); 
above helps me to restart the flow on button click
```